# Writing JUnit Test on a webapp that is calling another webapp without running the second webapp

Tags: java, junit, rmi

I have 2 separate webapps deployed in the same Tomcat instance. lets name these web apps A and B.

A is calling a method from B using RMI. Actually I want to write a JUnit Test for A without really deploying B.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your input is way too broad and unspecific. What have you tried so far? Just dropping **vague** requirements and then "no idea, please help" isn't a good way to start questions here.

Comment: to be more specific: what we cann do to mock a webservice

Comment: That very much depends on what level you are testing this overall. I think it would help to put up a [mcve]. It starts like: are we talking full **unit** test - so what is the context in which A is running? You see, for a *real* unit test, there is no concept of webapps and tomcat and what not. There are just classes, dependencies, mocks, and such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the second web application. E.g. you can use http://mock-server.com

Comment: Thanks it respond to my question